# Function composition operator doesn't respect default parameters?

Tags: swift, ubuntu

I am experimenting with a simple command line app on Linux, and I have the following code.

**Code**

```
import Glibc
import Foundation

infix operator |>> { associativity left }
func |>> <A, B, C>(f: A -> B, g: B -> C) -> A -> C {
    return { x in g(f(x)) }
}

func readln(max:Int = 8192) -> String? {
    assert(max > 0, "max must be between 1 and Int.max")
    var buf:Array<CChar> = []
    var c = getchar()
    while c != EOF && c != 10 && buf.count < max {
        buf.append(CChar(c))
        c = getchar()
    }
    buf.append(CChar(0))
    return buf.withUnsafeBufferPointer { String.fromCString($0.baseAddress) }
}

func myPrint(str: String?) {
    guard let unwrapped = str else {
        return;
    }
    print("\(unwrapped)")
}

//This compiles & runs
var input = readln()
myPrint(input)

//this does not!
let main = readln |>> myPrint
main()
```

**Compiler Output**

```
/home/**********/SwiftProjects/HelloPackage/Sources/main.swift:37:5: error: missing argument for parameter #1 in call
main()
    ^
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
error: exit(1): ["/home/**********/Swift/usr/bin/swift-build-tool", "-f", "/home/**********/SwiftProjects/HelloPackage/.build/debug/HelloPackage.o/llbuild.yaml"]
```

When I use my custom function composition operator, it does not let me use the same default parameter value as when I call the functions separately.

Can anyone explain what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closures are not, in contrast to functions, allowed to have default parameter values. So the above has nothing in specific to do with your custom operator (other than the fact that it returns a closure).

> Closure expression syntax can use constant parameters, variable
>   parameters, and inout parameters. **Default values cannot be provided**.

From [Language Guide - Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html).

Also, regarding your comparison of what runs, and what does not: note that the following are two quite different lines of code:

```
var input = readln()           // 'input' is a value: String?

// ...

let main = readln |>> myPrint  // 'main' is a closure: (Int) -> ()
main()                         // expected error
    /* since main is a closure, you've "lost" the default 
       value that is present in the _function_ readln     */
```